# Checking all files are encoded as UTF-8

Tags: windows, character-encoding, utility

Does anyone know of a Windows app that can scan through a directory and check which scripts are/aren't encoded as a specified charset (UTF-8 in this case)? I could do it manually, but that could take a while and is quite error prone!

Comment: What kind of scripts?  Unless a script has a BOM, it's can be difficult to tell if it's UTF-8 or ASCII.

Comment: If a file contains only 7-bit ASCII characters (i.e., only [0x00-0x7F]), then it is also UTF-8.

Comment: @brianegge: aye, I've just found this out the hard way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UTF-8 isn't a character set, it's an encoding for Unicode characters. And, since this is not programming related, I'm nudging it over to superuser.

If you *do* want to write a program for detecting those sequences, it's pretty easy:

```
Illegal UTF-8 initial sequences

UTF-8 Sequence       Reason for Illegality 
10xxxxxx             illegal as initial byte of character (80..BF) 
1100000x             illegal, overlong (C0 80..BF) 
11100000  100xxxxx   illegal, overlong (E0 80..9F) 
11110000  1000xxxx   illegal, overlong (F0 80..8F) 
11111000  10000xxx   illegal, overlong (F8 80..87) 
11111100  100000xx   illegal, overlong (FC 80..83) 
1111111x             illegal; prohibited by spec
```

Then, provided the first octet is legal, just remember that the number of octets forming a code point can be obtained by counting the number of `1` bits before the first `0` bit.

For example, `11110xxx` is the start of a 4-octet sequence so you should skip ahead 4 octets once you've established its legality.

The other thing to do is ensure that *all* continuation octets start with `10`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I use a command shell for-loop and dump the first few bytes of each file using my `hdump` utility, which displays the bytes of the file in hexadecimal form. I then look for the leading 3-byte UTF-8 signature (Byte Order Mark) at the start of each file.

My `hdump` utility is available at: http://david.tribble.com/programs.html

Comment: Not all UTF-8 files have a BOM.